# How do I find how many guilds my bot is in?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a discord bot, and I was just wondering: how do I find out how many guilds the bot is in? So that if I say  `-guilds` it'll tell me how many guilds it's in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll leave the command up to you, but to get the bot's available guilds, you must use `<Client>.guilds`.

This is a collection of guilds so to get the size of a collection all you have to do is `<Client>.guilds.size`

This information is also on the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds).

I hope this helps!

- Trifex

### Update

In the comments, [@NicoHd105](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12985179/nicohd105) noted that as of discord.js v12, the proper way to retrieve a collection of all guilds a bot is part of is `<Client>.guilds.cache`, meaning to get the size of the guilds you must use `<Client>.guilds.cache.size`!

Comment: due discord.js v12 it's now: "client.guilds.cache.size" btw

Comment: Bear in mind this is the count for the _client_, not the _bot_. If the bot is small with only one [shard](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#sharding), it'll be fine. But if you have shards on other clients, working out the count is a little more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

A .Net sample as well

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bot " + token);

HttpResponseMessage guildsResponse = await client2.GetAsync(@"https://discord.com/api/v6/users/@me/guilds");
jsonContent = await guildsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the method `.guilds` from [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds)

Comment: "guilds" is not even a method.. It's a property of the "client" object.