# discord.js v14 trying to do that my bot status will be the amount of servers that the bot is in them

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to do that my bot status will be the number of servers that he is in them.

I tried:

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
    // let guildsCount = client.guilds.size
  client.user.setPresence({
    activities: [
      { name: `${client.guilds.size} Servers!`, type: ActivityType.Watching },
    ],
    status: "online",
  });
});
```

and it's saying watching undefined servers!

I also tried:

```js
let guildsCount = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.);
```

but I don't know what to do after the "." to get the number of the guilds
I also tried:

```js
let guildsCount = client.guilds.cache.get()
```

but it didn't work either
saying watching undefined

Comment: Try `client.guilds.cache.size`. Relevant link: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572008/how-do-i-find-how-many-guilds-my-bot-is-in)

Comment: ty the client.guilds.cache.size worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**client.guilds.size** will return to you as **undefined**. You should use **client.guilds.cache.size**